# Debugging code that uses CGAL with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, cgal

I want to use Xcode to debug programs that use CGAL, but I can't get Xcode to run the program or stop at a breakpoint.  Xcode will compile the program (I verified this by running the result in a terminal window).  I can set breakpoints, but Xcode doesn't appear to run the program when I click the "run" button.

I stripped the code down to this simple example:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<K> Polygon_2;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
Point_2 pts[] = { Point_2(0.0,0.0), Point_2(2.0,0.0), Point_2(1.0,2.0) };
Polygon_2 poly( pts, pts + 3 );
if(poly.is_simple()) std::cout << "Polygon is simple\n";
else std::cout << "Polygon is not simple\n";
return 0;
}
```

I created the Xcode project using cgal_create_CMakeLists.  This script creates the project file for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

~/dev/CGAL-4.1/scripts/cgal_create_CMakeLists -s cgal_xcode -c Core
cmake -GXcode -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-O0 -DCGAL_DONT_OVERRIDE_CMAKE_FLAGS=TRUE .
```

I'm using CGAL 4.1 and Xcode 4.6.1 on OS X 10.8.3 (running on a MacBook, late 2008).

I'm very inexperienced with Xcode, so this is likely a simple mistake (a missed setting or the like).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question.  I didn't have an executable set for the Debug scheme.  Another post pointed me in the right direction, [Xcode 4.2 Product -> Run Greyed Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145429/xcode-4-2-product-run-greyed-out)

To set the executable I go to Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme...  This opens a dialog box.  On the left side of the box I click "Debug."  In the center region I select the "Info" tab.  Finally, in the center I change the "Executable" selection from "None" to my program's name.  Now my program runs and stops at breakpoints.

Simple enough once I found out where to look.